# Android project cannot build with gradle after importing a module

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, android-module

I created an android app and I wanted to include the vokaturi module. I changed the `vokaturi.gradle` file with  `"com.android.library"` and I included `":vokaturi"` module in the `settings.gradle` file and in the main app module I added `implementation project(':vokaturi')` When I try to syncronised main app module I get the error

```
Could not find :OpenVokaturi-Android:.
Required by:
    project :app > project :vokaturi
Search in build.gradle files
```

This is how my main app.gradle file looks like.

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.afinity"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    }
    dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation project(':vokaturi')
    }
```

And this is how the vokaturi.gradle file looks like

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs/aars'
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation(name: 'OpenVokaturi-Android', ext: 'aar')
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

I do not know what I do wrong...I am new at android, thank you all for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default name of the file is probably - OpenVokaturi-3-0-android.aar and not OpenVokaturi-Android which is why you're getting that error. Also this -

```
implementation(name: 'OpenVokaturi-3-0-android.aar', ext: 'aar')
```

should not be in your vokaturi module but rather in your app.gradle file. Add that line to your app gradle file and then include vokaturi directly as an aar file.

Comment: Thank you for response, I did this and I get the error :vokaturi:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

Comment: Remove this line from your library module build.gradle.            
             implementation(name: 'OpenVokaturi-Android', ext: 'aar')

Comment: Thank you, the name of the modules differed but it doesn't work if I delete the line from vokaturi module :( If I let it there and in the app module also it works

Comment: And I have another problem too, in this case it works but it creates to app on the device, not just one. Could you help me with that also?

Comment: This error appeared when I try to build the app after I delete that line from vokaturi.gradle file                      
  org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':vokaturi:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
 ... 34 more